# EntityFramework Multiple Where

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am wondering, if I use multiple `Where(...)` methods one after the other, is EntityFramework smart enough to combine it in a resulting query. Let's say I have:

```
context.Items
    .Where(item => item.Number > 0)
    .Where(item => item.Number < 5)
    .ToList();
```

Will the resulting SQL query be the same as if I write:

```
context.Items
    .Where(item => item.Number > 0 && item.Number < 5)
    .ToList();
```

Are there any behind-the-scenes optimizations for multiple Where clause?

Comment: They should both translate to the same SQL for any major provider. You can always try both and see what SQL each produces.

Comment: Yes multiple where is the same as joining conditions with && (which you could have verified yourself in about one minute by the way).

Comment: @Evk I couldn't verify any JIT or syntax sugar optimizations fast without digging into docs and IL though. Please see my last question. Thanks.

Comment: You can view the SQL that the EF provider is generating by attaching something to the Log property. `context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);`

Comment: @Spivonious as a rule I call `.ToString()` on my query. Log option is very useful. Like you can register logger only for debug to see queries when you develop an app. I didn't know about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are. It is not Entity Framework that does this. It is actually the SQL Provider Factory's job to compose the query for the database. Depending on the database you use, this code will be from different sources.

For MSSQL, the code is Microsoft's and is in the library `System.Data.SqlClient`. If you look at your connection element in your web.config, you should notice the attribute "providerName".

Inside of this library, or libraries similar to it, often a recursive visitor pattern is employed to navigate through the defined Expression Tree object graph in order to produce the most efficient query possible.

Using multiple where clauses is very easy to detect and optimize, the place that these sort of libraries have trouble tends to be with deeply nested projections.

You can see the SQL produced by your query if you use

```
context.Items
.Where(item => item.Number > 0)
.Where(item => item.Number < 5)
.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Is there a way so that `OR` is used instead of `AND` if I use multiple where?

Comment: @shashwat - It is possible to accomplish that, however, it can be rather complicated. There are simple versions of doing that and there are difficult versions, which you need will depend on the overall structure of your approach. That would be well served as its own question.

Comment: Thanks @TravisJ.
I was just wondering if there is something built-in or simple solution. It that's the case, I will build something simple just to fit my needs. Thanks again!